# How to modify a mocked object in the middle of a test without the original reference?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

Say I have the following code in a file called `api.ts`:

```
/* api.ts */
type Api = {
  getNumber(): number
}

const configure(): Api {
  return {
    getNumber:() => {/*Concrete implementation here*/} 
  }
}
```

And the configure method is used by a method `foo` that I want to test:

```
/* Foo.ts */
import { configure } from './api'
  const api = configure()
  const foo = () => {
    return api.getNumber()
  }
```

I create a setup file that sets the mock for `configure` globally with jest:

```
/*jest.setup.js*/
jest.mock('./api', () => ({
  configure: jest.fn(() => ({
    getNumber: jest.fn(),
  }))
}))
```

Now I want to be able to test `foo` in a test file, changing the api result in the middle of the test like this:

```
/* Foo.test.ts */
  import { configure } from './api'

  const api = configure() // Returns the mocked instance

  it('foo should work for different results', async () => {
    api.getNumber.mockResolvedValue(1)
    const result1 = foo()
    // Do assertions

    api.getNumber.mockResolvedValue(2)
    const result2 = foo()
    // Do other assertions
  })
```

However this doesn't work, as the api call doesn't return the correct value that I am trying to set with `mockResolvedValue`. My guess is this happens because accessing the `configure` method inside `Foo.test.ts` returns a different instance to the one that I access in `Foo.ts` meaning that any modifications that I make in the test file won't affect the api class being used in `Foo.ts`

If I am correct in this, how can I possibly make this code work, so I can change the return type of the method of the object returned by `configure`?

Answer (score 0):

you can utilize the manual mock implementation provided by Jest.
Create a manual mock file for api.ts

```js
/* __mocks__/api.ts */
const apiMock = {
  getNumber: jest.fn(),
};

export const configure = jest.fn(() => apiMock)
```

then update your test file to use the manual mock implementation

```js
import { configure } from './api'
const api = configure() as { getNumber: jest.Mock<number, []> } // Cast the type of api to include the jest.Mock

const foo = () => {
  return api.getNumber()
}
it('foo should work for different results', async () => {
  api.getNumber.mockResolvedValue(1)
  const result1 = await foo()
  // Do assertions

  api.getNumber.mockResolvedValue(2)
  const result2 = await foo()
  // Do other assertions
})
```